how to fix Failed assertion: line 3345 pos 14: 'renderer.parent != null': is not true
[log] onChange Change { currentState: HomeState.pageChangedState(index: 1, length: 3), nextState: HomeState.pageChangedState(index: 0, length: 3) }
[log] 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 3345 pos 14: 'renderer.parent != null': is not true.
I entered the link 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart' and put the renderer and renderer.parent with the && condition and set each unequal distance to null, but I still got an error. Thank you for your help.

Can you provide the code where this error originated? I got somewhat same error not long ago. I might be able to help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
